# How to return back parameter values when validation is failed in Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express

After validation and some fields are not satisfied with the validation rule it will redirect to the registration page, now after the direction I would like to retain the values inputted by the user and assign it to the corresponding input field. I haven't seen this in expressjs but with PHP, Ruby they do have this feature.

This part here I want to return back the params value to front-end so that the user wont re-enter the values.

```
if ( req.session.flash_has_errors() ) {
    return res.redirect_with_session('/register/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring variables for username and other stuff. You save it after post.
After validation you can render new registrationpage with this values.

```
router.post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {

  let username = req.body.username;
  if (validation){

  }else{
     res.render('./signup', { username: username });
  }
});
```